# How to extract a github repos domain from the description?

Tags: spring-boot, github, artificial-intelligence

I have a spring boot app that takes a github repository and analyzes the repo via certain tools. I want to add a functionality that requires me to know the domain of the repo ie(https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer is system design && https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow is ai). Is there a way to determine the repo's domain via some tool that would be accessed by spring boot?

I already have the description at my disposal. What I need is a way to extract the info from the description ie some text classification tool that will take the description as an input and return the appropriate domain

I have thought about using chatgpt or bard nbut i am not sure if i can get the answer in the desirable format ie one word

Answer (score 0):

use the GitHub API:

1. Utilize the GitHub API to fetch information about the repository from its URL.
2. You can use the endpoint https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo, where :owner is the repository owner's name, and :repo is the repository name.
3. Examine the repository description for specific keywords or indicators of the repository's domain.